# bootstrap card how to integrate flex using cards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-modal

[code container_row_col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZhh0.png)

I am using bootstrap card with attribute like [container, row and col] to establish  a horizontal flex container. But it doesnt work. I think the problem comes from [col]  but i cant figure out what to do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP3zO.png)

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved my problem. The problem why i wasnt able to use my flex properties with "row" id was because after <div id"row"> i implemented another <div id"bear">. I must use the <div id"col> following  <div id"row">. So what i did is to delete the <div id"bear"> and i implemented my id"bear" at the same div containing row, so <div id"row bear">.
Apparently with bootstrap we cant use a div between "row" and "col"(if we want to keep "row" as a flex) .